# How to configure baud rate for transmitting data using HAL_UART_Transmit() in STM32F103C8T6?

Tags: stm32, putty, uart, stm32cubemx

I am using STM32F103C8T6 board and CubeMX to generate the code. I transmit the data via UART using the function HAL_UART_Transmit(). I configured the baud rate as 9600 in CubeMX and I chose the speed as 9600 in Putty also. Still I got some junk values only. How to sync up my data transmission?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How are you outputting the characters in your program?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same and got it working. Please make sure all other transmission settings are the same and check your code.
My Settings are: 
Mode: Asynchronous
Hardware Flow Control: Disable
Baud Rate: 9600
Word length: 8 Bits
Parity: None
Stop Bits: 1
Data Direction: Receive and Transmit
Over Sampling: 16 Samples

It looks like this:
[STM32CubeMX parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fztvl.png)

In Putty make sure you have
Speed: 9600;
Data bits: 8
Stop bits: 1
Parity: None
Flow control: None
to match the settings!
It looks like this:

[PuTTY configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4YIX.png)

Lastely my code to send "Hello World" to the PuTTY console is:

```
char* msg2 = "Hello World\n\r";
HAL_StatusTypeDef status = HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, msg2, strlen(msg2), 100);
```

make sure to 
    #include "string.h"
to use strlen()

I hope this helps, make sure you don't miss something :)

Answer (score 0):

`USART1 -> BRR = USART_CLOCK / BAUD;`

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect the GND pin from the board to your UART adapter?

Because it should work if you did call the init fuction CubeMX generated. Your junk values seem more connected to that than the baudrate.